# when creating a pdf using pdfcopy returns a empty document

Tags: java, itext

when I create a pdf using pdfcopy, the pdf that returns to the client is empty or has 1 line, but when I open it on an explorer it has all the data that I merge, im using itextsharp 5

this is where I make the merge:

```
try {
    document.close();

    PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(pdfStream.toByteArray());
    //se crea el documento final
    Document documentFinal=  new Document(PageSize.LETTER, left, right, top, bottom);
    PdfCopy pdf_copy = new PdfCopy(documentFinal, pdfStreamFinal);
    PdfWriter pdfFinal = PdfWriter.getInstance(documentFinal, pdfStreamFinal);
    pdfFinal.setInitialLeading(20);

    documentFinal.open();

    //CONTENIDO PARA PODER UNIR LOS PDFs
    PdfPTable tContenido = new PdfPTable(1);
    tContenido.addCell(Celda(pdfEl.textocelda(false, "DESCRIPCIÓN GENERAL", 6.0f), false, 1,1, BaseColor.WHITE));
    documentFinal.add(tContenido);  

    //INICIAR CARGA DE DATOS EN DOCUMENTO FINAL
    PdfReader readerR = new PdfReader(reader2);
    int pagesR = readerR.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int p = 1; p <= pagesR; p++)
        pdf_copy.addPage(pdf_copy.getImportedPage(readerR, p));
    readerR.close();

    //se unen los demas PDFs
    for (PdfReader read : readerList) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(read);
        int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int p = 1; p <= pages; p++)
            pdf_copy.addPage(pdf_copy.getImportedPage(reader, p));
        reader.close();
    }

    documentFinal.close();
    pdf_copy.close();

} catch (BadElementException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Calle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Calle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (DocumentException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Calle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return pdfStreamFinal.toByteArray();
```

then I send it like this

```
return Response.ok(makePDF.makePDFEjecutivo(idalle)).header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfName + ".pdf").build();
```

this is the document open on document viewer [document on document viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHcxh.jpg)

this is the same document open on mozzila firefox [open on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEvOY.jpg)

how can I solve this problem? I need the same document showing the same info on both places.

Side note: when I change the type "inline" to a "attachment" it only shows the info from the 1st img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this variable:

```
PdfWriter pdfFinal;
```

Because when you are creating an instance of this variable, the document referenced by `PdfCopy pdf_copy` it is override and creates a new empty document.